# How to iterate the data from XMLElement using foreach in C#

Tags: c#, ssis, mdm

I want to iterate the data from XMLElement. In List i have 10 row of records . each row contains again list of values. In row, each values need to store into somString type.

Below is the XMLElement getting from List

```
<ROW id="1">
   <D n="6721">10128</D>
   <D n="6724">CL</D>
   <D n="6771">*</D>
   <D n="6773">ACT</D>
   <D n="6774">PHON</D>
   <D n="6775">04-MAR-2018 21:54</D>
   <D n="6779">MEP-IU</D>
   <D n="6780">MEP-IU-010</D>
   <D n="6782">CWP2B19-113</D>
   <D n="6792">11410</D>
   <D n="6809"/>
   <D n="6880"/>
   <D n="11651">Tap is not working in the Back of the Apt  
                Name: Alex 
                Contact : 971-566826978</D>
   <D n="100410">40977</D>
   <D n="101312">AHMED.ALI@MERAAS.AE</D>
   <D n="101313">HANDOVER</D>
 </ROW>
```

I tried this code for i tried to iterating data, but i m getting very 1st element only not remaining elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
{
    if (nodeList[i].InnerText.Length > 0)
    {
        string name =(string) i.FirstChild.Value;                     
        MessageBox.Show(nodeList[i].InnerText);
    }
}
```

But i m getting filed column value only .. how to get remaining data from XMLElement.

In List i have 10 row of records . each row contains again list of values. In row, each values need to store into somString type.

I want to extract list of all records from response. I m not sure how to go about writing a code for to filter the data.

Kindly refer some sample for this one.

Comment: This XML structure is the same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335910/how-to-extract-the-data-from-soap-response-in-c-sharp/58340181#comment103056597_58340181

Comment: What is nodeList, please show how it is being set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **quick** and **dirty** way to get at the values, this can be improved by removing the hard-coded values and checking for objects prior to accessing them.

EDIT: XML structure is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335910/how-to-extract-the-data-from-soap-response-in-c-sharp/).

```
            using (var stream = new StreamReader("Response.xml"))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);

                var nodes = doc.Elements().Descendants()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == XName.Get("ROW", "http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result"));

                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    if (node.FirstAttribute != null)
                    {
                        var firstAttribute = node.FirstAttribute;
                        Console.WriteLine($"{firstAttribute.Name.LocalName} - {firstAttribute.Value}");

                        var children = node.Descendants();
                        if (children.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var child in children)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{child.FirstAttribute.Value}:{child.Value}");
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for response bro I used alternate ways to filter the records

Answer (score 0):

using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string result1 = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(result1);

```
                xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(result1);
                XmlNodeList nodeList;

                if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes["xmlns:soapenv"] != null)
                {
                    string xmlns = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes["xmlns:soapenv"].Value;
                    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);

                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("df", "http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result");


                    nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/df:MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result/df:GRIDRESULT/df:GRID/df:DATA/df:ROW[*]", nsmgr);
                }
                else
                {
                    nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/df:MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result/df:GRIDRESULT/df:GRID/df:DATA/df:ROW[*]");
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (nodeList[i].InnerText.Length > 0)
                    {




                        String ctr_code = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                        String ctr_status = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
                        String ctr_org = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
                        String ctr_type = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[3].InnerText;
                        String ctr_contactsource = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[4].InnerText;
                        String ctr_created = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[5].InnerText;
                        String ctr_servicecategory = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[6].InnerText;
                        String ctr_serviceproblem = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[7].InnerText;
                        String ctr_object = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[8].InnerText;
                        String ctr_contactinfoid = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[9].InnerText;
                        String ctr_contactnote = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[10].InnerText;
                        String ctr_desc = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[11].InnerText;
                        String ctr_note = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[12].InnerText;
                        String ctr_event = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[13].InnerText;
                        String ctr_createdby = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[14].InnerText;
                        String ctr_mrc = nodeList[i].ChildNodes[15].InnerText;






                    }
                }               

            }
        }
    }
```